# How can i display my RadioSelect Widget in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-widget

I have a model, form, view and i cannot seem to actually display the RadioSelect widget. it doesnt show anything, i think everything is fine except the views, however, i am unsure.
I basically want someone to choose and option from the two radio buttons, submit to then be able to register as one of the two options but like i said i cant even get the buttons to show.

views.py

```
def registration(request):
    reg = Registration.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'HTML/Registration.html', {"reg":reg})
```

models.py

```
class Registration(models.Model):
    OPTIONS = (
            ('COUNS','Counsellor'),
            ('CLIENT','Client'),
            )
    SELECT = models.CharField(max_length=15,
                        choices=OPTIONS)
```

forms.py

```
class Registration(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Registration
    fields = '__all__'
    widgets = {'SELECT': forms.RadioSelect}
```

HTML

```
<form method="POST">
 {% csrf_token %}
<div class="d-flex justify-content-between flex-wrap flex-md-nowrap align-items-center pt-3 pb-2 mb-3 
border-bottom">
 <h1 class="h2">Registration</h1>
</div>

{% render_field reg.SELECT %}

<div class="form-row">
  <div class="col pt-md-2">
    <input type="submit" value="Next" class="btn btn-primary" style="float: right;">
  </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: You are referring to the model, not the form. Please do *not* give the model and the form the same name. It is quite common to a dd a suffix `Form` to the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referring to the model, not the form. Please do *not* give the model and the form the same name. It is quite common to a dd a suffix `Form` to the form.

```
# app/forms.py

from django import forms
from app.models import Registration

class RegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Registration
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = { 'SELECT': forms.RadioSelect }
```

Then in the view, you can create such form as:

```
# app/views.py

from app.forms import RegistrationForm
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def registration(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        reg = RegistrationForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if reg.is_valid():
            reg.save()
            return redirect('name-of-some-view')
    else:
        reg = RegistrationForm()
    return render(request, 'HTML/Registration.html', {'reg': reg})
```

> **Note**: In case of a successful POST request, you should make a [**`redirect`**
>   [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)
>   to implement the [*Post/Redirect/Get* pattern [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).
>   This avoids that you make the same POST request when the user refreshes the
>   browser.

Comment: Out of all my forms thats the only one without form at the end, thanks for spotting that. It displays now.